# Magento Enterprise controller override

Tags: php, magento, controllers

I am trying to override the Enterprise/CatalogEvent/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/EventController.php.

The problem is the config.xml. How do I follow the naming convention of Magento.
The following is the config.xml file

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <Mynamespace_catalogevent before="Enterprise_CatalogEvent">Mynamespace_CatalogEvent_Adminhtml</Mynamespace_catalogevent>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
             </adminhtml>
        </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: its not working.. sorry for the late reply...

Answer (score 3):

Based on the seemingly correct xpath and attribute above, you will need to have an EventController.php file under Mynamespace/CatalogEvent/controllers/Adminhtml/.

This style of rewrite is the latest in Magento (deprecating previous methods). Effectively, you are injecting a directory before the Enterprise directory, and routing will start there. Because controller class definitions are not available to the autoloader, they are included by taking the module argument and translating that to a directory. In core Magento routing though the controller file is determined via `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::getControllerFileName()` and `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getModuleDir()` (among others). The way that it's evaluated means that after two directory levels in your module (eg. Mynamespace/CatalogEvent), the next directory will be "controllers".

Ensure that your EventController class definition is located according to the above, that your  action matches the action you are overriding, and that your classname matches your path, and you'll be good to go.

The difficult thing is that if anything is "off" about your structure and syntax (save the incorrect classname), the router will end up resolving to the Enterprise action controller.

Comment: Hello, I am having a very similar issue and I appologize but the above isn't seeming to click with me. Its probably due to it being a friday at 5pm. Can you please give an example of the file structure and maybe some code examples of this new way of doing rewrites? or at least give a link to somewhere that has some of this? Here is my question fyi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483967/magento-attempting-to-override-a-controller/16484144?noredirect=1#comment23667570_16484144

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, and the simple solution to my problem was to ensure that the `_Adminthml` portion of the class was included in both my local controller as well as the controller I was overridding.  In your case:

```
<Mynamespace_catalogevent before="Enterprise_CatalogEvent_Adminhtml">
    Mynamespace_CatalogEvent_Adminhtml
</Mynamespace_catalogevent>
```

Your example is missing the `_Adminhtml` on the `before` attribute.

This is on Magento Enterprise v1.12.0.2

Hope this helps.