# Magento: Attempting to override a controller

Tags: magento, controller, overriding

So I am trying to override the core CustomerController massDelete action. This is what I have so far:

```
config.xml

<frontend>
  <routers>
    <customer_massdelete>
      <args>
        <modules>
          <MyModule_MyExtension before="Mage_Adminhtml">MyModule_MyExtension</MyModule_MyExtension>
        </modules>
      </args>
    </customer_massdelete>
  </routers>
</frontend>
```

My Controller:

```
app/code/local/MyModule/MyExtension/controllers/CustomerController.php

<?php
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php';
class MyModule_MyExtension_CustomerController extends Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController {
  public function massDeleteAction() { 
   die('my controller');
  }
}
```

Yet when i run a mass delete the die that i put in their controller is run instead. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Tried out solution as follows:

```
<config>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <adminhtml>          
        <args>
          <modules>
            <MyModule_MyExtension before="Mage_Adminhtml">MyModule_MyExtension</MyModule_MyExtension>
          </modules>
        </args>
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
</config>
```

Still nothing...

**UPDATE 2:**

My final config.xml was like this:

```
<config>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <adminhtml>      
        <args>
          <modules>
            <Mymodule_Myextension before="Mage_XmlConnect_Adminhtml">Mymodule_Myextension</Mymodule_Myextension>
          </modules>
        </args>      
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
</config>
```

However, if I have before="Mage_XmlConnect_Adminhtml" then I get some override issues when trying to go to most index pages. However if I go any lower in priority it doesn't override. So I am stuck again.

Comment: is your module declared? (`app/etc/modules/MyModule_MyExtension.xml`) cache is flushed?

Comment: Yes module is declared and working for a bunch of other things. Cache is off but i manually flushed it just in case. Still nothing

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Nothing in any of the logs either

Comment: is there any more of my code I could offer up that might help us come to a solution?

Comment: Try my post on [general Magento controller & controller rewrite debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15834524/833795)

Comment: check if another module override this action

Comment: Sorry for the delay, busy weekend, @benmarks I went through that post and still couldn't figure out what was going on. I'll give it some more time today. @OSdave I put a `die()` inside of the controller im overriding and it dies which means that nothing else is overriding it.

Comment: are you certain all files and folders are correctly spelled and placed? paste a screenshot of it, a new pair of eyes usually works better to find the typos

Comment: I wish i could. Unfortunately I was asked by my boss to obfuscate my code a decent amount. However, what I have above is exactly what I am looking at with my module name / extension name obfuscated. Which file would you otherwise like to see?

Answer (score 0):

i guess your config.xml is false, you might try:

```
<admin>
   <routers>
      <adminhtml>
         <args>
           <modules>
             <MyModule_MyExtension before="Mage_Adminhtml">MyModule_MyExtension</MyModule_MyExtension>
           </modules>
         </args>
      </adminhtml>
   </routers>
</admin>
```

reference: http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/

Comment: I made the change and still nothing. See update for current config

Comment: @BillGarrison just tried it out, the referenced code is working perfectly for me..sure, that you didn't just forget to activate your modul?

Comment: Yeah I had the module on for other things. This is just one more step in the process. From all the other examples i'm seeing this SHOULD work...I know i have to be missing something small...i just can't see it

Comment: maybe compiler is activated?

Comment: Double checked. Compiler is not active

Comment: what's your magento version?

Comment: Maybe this link can help you? It's for Enterprise Edition and uses another folder structure: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8007210

Comment: Thank you for the point in that direction. That may help, however I have a die() in the core massDelete action method and its dying out. This leads me to believe that its using core and not Enterprise which would mean i shouldn't have an issue doing a rewrite this way.

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of research I finally figured out the issue. My issue was with the `before="Mage_Adminhtml"` in `config.xml`. Due to the way enterprise works it was not enough to override the top level class.

I used `print_r(Mage::getConfig()->getNode('admin/routers/adminhtml'), true)` to figure out all the modules overriding it and worked through the list. `Mage_XmlConnect_Adminhtml` was the last class that overrode this method before enterprise methods.

My final config.xml was like this:

```
<config>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <adminhtml>      
        <args>
          <modules>
            <Mymodule_Myextensionbefore="Mage_XmlConnect_Adminhtml">Mymodule_Myextension</Mymodule_Myextension>
          </modules>
        </args>      
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
</config>
```

It now works perfectly (Edit: Nope it doesnt...see comment below)

Comment: So actually I am having a bit of an issue with this. If I have before="Mage_XmlConnect_Adminhtml" then I get some override issues when trying to go to most index pages. However if I go any lower in priority it doesn't override. So I am stuck again.